# Multiple source vertices for Julia's Graphs Dijkstra algorithm

Tags: graph, julia, dijkstra

I am trying to compute distances for all vertices. Documentations says that Dijkstra algorithm can take as argument for source multiple vertices but there is no explanation for input type. It works for one vertex when I input **[v1]**. I tried to find type of this argument and it says it is **Array{ExVertex, 1}** so I tried to input method **vertices(g1)** but It does not work. Any help ???

```
using Graphs

g1 = Graphs.graph(Graphs.ExVertex[], Graphs.ExEdge{Graphs.ExVertex}[], is_directed=false)
d = "dist"

v1 = add_vertex!(g1, "a")
v2 = add_vertex!(g1, "b")
v3 = add_vertex!(g1, "c")
v4 = add_vertex!(g1, "d")
v5 = add_vertex!(g1, "e")
e12 = add_edge!(g1, v3, v1)
e12.attributes[d]=1.0

e13 = add_edge!(g1, v3, v2)
e13.attributes[d]=2.0

e14 = add_edge!(g1, v3, v4)
e14.attributes[d]=3.0

e15 = add_edge!(g1, v3, v5)
e15.attributes[d]=4.0

epi = AttributeEdgePropertyInspector{Float64}(d)
sp = dijkstra_shortest_paths(g1, epi, ???) # what to input for more source vertices
```

Answer (score 1):

**Aside:** Perhaps the confusion is because `dijkstra_shortest_paths` with the 2nd argument an `Graphs.AbstractEdgePropertyInspector` comes only in a version taking a `Vector` of vertices as the 3rd argument, forcing the use of `[v1]` even for a single source. 
Use `?dijkstra_shortest_paths` at the REPL for more info.

**Regarding multiple sources:**
`dijkstra_shortest_paths` computes the distance (and paths) from a set of vertices to *all* other vertices. The third argument is the groups of source vertices i.e. one can reach *any* of these source vertices with *zero* cost (in moves or distance).

If the intention was to compute the distance from all vertices to a single destination, `dijkstra_shortest_paths` can still be used, by putting the destination vertex, say `v1`, as a single source (3rd arg) and reversing the distances (in case the graph is directed).

Alternatively, if the intention was to find the (different) distances to all vertices from several sources, `dijkstra_shortest_paths` should be run several times. This is not the same as finding the distance from several sources, which means the path to a destination vertex can choose which of the source vertices to start at.

Comment: To compute the distances between all pairs of vertices there are more efficient algorithms (see `floyd_warshall`).

Comment: Intention was to calculate distances for every vertex in the graph to all other vertices. I figured it out by calling Dijkstra multiple times in loop but I wondered if there is some cleanest solution.

Comment: So the previous comment should apply (Floyd-Warshall). Do a `?floyd_warshall` for the syntax.

Comment: I solved this but new problem occurs that now i have to consider multiple shortest paths from source to target.

Comment: Multiple paths are a possibility. In an extreme case there could be *exponential* number of shortest paths. Selecting one of them is easy. Finding all is also easy to code, but could take a long time (e.g. consider two points connected by a series of crosses - ASCII-graphically: `source<><><><>destination`)

Comment: I know. I was curios and i run this command `println(dijkstra_shortest_paths(g1, epi, [v2]))` and product was this `DijkstraStates{ExVertex,Float64,MutableBinaryHeap{DijkstraHEntry{ExVertex,Float64},LessThan},Int64}([vertex [2] "b",vertex [2] "b",vertex [2] "b"],[2,2,2],[1.0,0.0,0.5],[2,2,2],MutableBinaryHeap(),[1,0,2])`. I think that last array `[1,0,2]` is the number of shortest paths but I am not sure.